# Error While Implementing Bottom Navigation bar in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation-bar

I am fairly new in android development.
I tried implementing navigation bar in my app which switch from fragment A to Fragment B.
And in Fragment A there is a floating action button which points to Fragment c.
I have no problem switching from fragment A to B through navigation bar but when i try to switch to fragment c from Floating action button it gives me ERROR.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{65bf79f V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1529 #7f0800b2 app:id/frameLayout} does not have a NavController set**

Here is the codes:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dateView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dateTextView)
        dateView.text = getMonth()

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_frag) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)

        val chartFrag = ChartsFragment()
        val infoData = info_data()

        val botNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.botNavigation)
        botNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.menu_statement ->{
                    setCurrentFragment(infoData)
                }
                R.id.menu_charts ->{
                    setCurrentFragment(chartFrag)
                }
            }
            true
        }

    }


    fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply{
        replace(R.id.nav_host_frag, fragment)
        commit()
    }

    fun getMonth():String{
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy")
        val date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.time)
        return date
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**info_data.kt**

```
class info_data : Fragment() {
    val dataSet = dataSource().loadData()
    val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(dataSet)

    companion object{
        var income = 0.0
        var expense = 0.0
    }

    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_data, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val tvExpense = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvExpense)
        tvExpense.text = "Expense : \n$ "+expense.toString()

        val tvIncome = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvIncome)
        tvIncome.text = "Income : \n$ "+income.toString()

        val tvTotal = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTotal)
        tvTotal.text = "Total : \n$ "+grandTotal().toString()

        val rv= view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        rv.adapter = adapter
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val floatingBtn = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabBtn)
        floatingBtn.setOnClickListener(){
            goToNextScreen(view)
        }
    }

    fun goToNextScreen(view: View){
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_info_data_to_form_data2)
    }

    fun grandTotal():Double{
        val inc = income
        val exp = expense
        val total = inc-exp
        return total
    }
}
```

**Errors:
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)

at com.example.myapplication.info_data.goToNextScreen(info_data.kt:58)

at com.example.myapplication.info_data.onViewCreated$lambda-0(info_data.kt:53)**

Comment: You are using a `NavHostFragment`, which means you should never being doing a `FragmentTransaction` at all. Is there a reason you're not following the [guide to setting up your bottom navigation with a NavController](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation)?

Comment: Thank You So much. Thank you